# Multiple testing and logistic regression

Tags: logistic, multiple-comparisons

I want to perform a number of univariate regressions with different symptoms (e.g. fever, cough, sneezing) as the response variable and one categorical variable (which is always the same each time) as an explanatory variable - age group (0-4, 5-14, 15-64, 65+). In total there are 18 symptoms so hence, I want to do 18 regressions and want to correct for multiple testing using Holm's method.

For each regression I get 4 p-values - one overall age group p-value and 3 p-values comparing individual age groups to a reference age group (15-64). I am unsure about how to calculate confidence intervals and adjusted p-values using Holm's method in this scenario. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The R `rms` package supports general simultaneous confidence intervals.  The analyst can specify a series of comparisons, and simultaneous adjustment will be done over all the current set of comparisons.  For more information see the `rms` `contrast.rms` function, along with `Predict` and other functions.  Here's an example using ols.  Substitute lrm for ols to do binary or proportional odds logistic regression.

```
require(rms)
set.seed(1)
n <- 800
treat <- factor(sample(c('drug','placebo'), n,TRUE))
sex   <- factor(sample(c('female','male'),  n,TRUE))
age   <- rnorm(n, 50, 10)
y     <- .05*age + (sex=='female')*(treat=='drug')*.05*abs(age-50) + rnorm(n)
f     <- ols(y ~ rcs(age,4)*treat*sex)
d     <- datadist(age, treat, sex); options(datadist='d')

# show separate estimates by treatment and sex

plot(Predict(f, age, treat, sex='female'))
plot(Predict(f, age, treat, sex='male'))
ages  <- seq(35,65,by=5); sexes <- c('female','male')
w     <- contrast(f, list(treat='drug',    age=ages, sex=sexes),
                     list(treat='placebo', age=ages, sex=sexes),
                     conf.type='simultaneous'))
xYplot(Cbind(Contrast, Lower, Upper) ~ age | sex, data=w,
       ylab='Drug - Placebo')
xYplot(Cbind(Contrast, Lower, Upper) ~ age, groups=sex, data=w,
       ylab='Drug - Placebo', method='alt bars')
```

Answer (score 0):

For confidence interval, I think you can just use the logistic regression outputs.
For adjust p-values, refer to this wiki link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm%E2%80%93Bonferroni_method

To my understanding, you are first test an overall age group, then testing a nested hypothesis. I would recommend you test overall group effects first, then go deeper to test individual groups.

Comment: No, 95% confidence intervals are constructed such that, with a single data sample, the actual point is within the interval with probability $0.05$. It does not account for multiple testing. The probability of finding a significant effect for at least one measure (when there is none, assuming measures are independent) would be $1-0.95^{18}\approx 0.6>>0.05$.

Comment: @Nameless I'm pretty sure that your interpretation of a 95%-confidence interval is wrong. In a frequentist framework, the value is *fixed* and the endpoints of the confidence interval are random variables. For a *single sample,* the confidence interval either includes the true value or not. To say a single confidence interval includes the true value with a probability is not applicable. See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11609/clarification-on-interpreting-confidence-intervals/11727#11727) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/6652/21054).

Comment: Yes, please replace "probability" with "percent of cases" above. Which, as it happens, is the same in a frequentist framework..

Answer (score 0):

So lets imagine there are only 2 symptoms and I got the following results:

```
### Fever: ###

Overall p-value
Wald test:
----------

Chi-squared test:
X2 = 16.8, df = 3, P(> X2) = 0.00078

Coefficients:
                            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                   1.5849     0.1103  14.366  < 2e-16 ***
relevel(agegp, "15-64")0-4    0.6323     0.3361   1.881  0.05994 .  
relevel(agegp, "15-64")5-14   0.7273     0.2182   3.333  0.00086 ***
relevel(agegp, "15-64")65+   -1.0253     0.6364  -1.611  0.10718

### Cough ###

Overall p-value
Wald test:
----------

Chi-squared test:
X2 = 8.5, df = 3, P(> X2) = 0.036

Coefficients:
                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                   2.2693     0.1416  16.024  < 2e-16 ***
relevel(agegp, "15-64")0-4   -0.3234     0.3189  -1.014  0.31051    
relevel(agegp, "15-64")5-14  -0.5850     0.2050  -2.854  0.00432 ** 
relevel(agegp, "15-64")65+   -0.7652     0.7945  -0.963  0.33544
```

What would be my adjusted p-values (using Holm's method) in this scenario of having only 2 symptoms and how would I calculate confidence intervals?