# Confidence intervals for regression interpretation

Tags: regression, confidence-interval

I have done linear regression and plotted the data, the regression line and also the confidence interval (for 95% confidence).  However it seems that most of the data points fall outside the confidence interval.  So how am I supposed to interpret the confidence interval.  It cannot be *I am 95% confident that the data point will be this close to the regression line* since a lot more than 5% of the data points do not fall in that area.  So what does it mean then?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with confidence interval?
A ci is usually calculated for estimates. In your case these are the beta coefficients which describe the effect of your expl. variables on your dependent variable.

Comment: I am using the code here http://www.students.ncl.ac.uk/tom.holderness/software/pythonlinearfit  I guess I'm just asking how I interpret the confidence intervals in the plot

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by confidence interval. It sounds to me like you have a confidence interval for the fitted model (the regression line), which would not include on average 95% of the observations or anything close to that value. There is a *prediction interval* for the OLS model which may be what you were expecting?

Comment: The calculation used to get the confidence interval is in the link from my previous comment.  I'm just looking for an intuitive interpretation.

Comment: If you're interested in the intepretation of a 95% CI, there are many questions/answers here on CV, e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26450/why-does-a-95-ci-not-imply-a-95-chance-of-containing-the-mean/26457#26457 Thus this is a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clarification on interpreting confidence intervals?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11609/clarification-on-interpreting-confidence-intervals)

Comment: Am I reading the linked Python script right? It seems to at least intend to compute a prediction interval, which seems at odds with what the OP is describing here?

Comment: Not that anyone would care, but I think I now know what is calculated in the python script: http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/1/6/0/16076faed456501df0ab50f07d8db249.png which seems to be hyperbolic confidence bands for the joint regression coefficients, if I understood correctly. Never seen that before but it appears to be a CI for the whole regression line rather than just the regression parameters pointwise.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two 95% CI you can derive from your data. One is the **95% CI of the regression line**, which is the red one in the attached illustration. The code you provided is intended for plotting this 95% CI. Now, because it's for the line, not for the data points, as you get more data, the precision improves, and the band will narrow down. Your cited code is a somewhat special case because the sample size is only 7, so the 95% CI of the line happened to include about 90% of the data points; it's just a coincidence.

[image]

The interval that approximately includes 95% of the data points is shown below in green. I am not sure what it is called, but generally from what I have collected on this site, it should not be called confidence interval. I think you're looking to get these kind of lines, but have been using the incorrect code.

The one that matters more often is the red one. And for proper interpretation, other users have provided links to some useful posts.

[image]

Comment: OK so the interpretation is that you can be 95% confident that the regression line is within that interval for those data points.  Thanks

Comment: @user1893354 Correct if you're talking about the red one. That's the 95% CI of the slope.

Comment: OP no, you cannot. The interpretation of a CI is subtle, follow the links above. @Penguin_Knight the second part of your answer is usually called the prediction interval and should not be called a CI. See http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/intervals/

Comment: What are the green lines exactly? If they are intended to include 95% (or whatever) of the *distribution*, then they are not a confidence interval: they would be a tolerance interval. If they are intended to include a specified number of *future* (independent) points, they would be a form of prediction interval; and if they must include a given number of the *data* points, they must be related to empirical quantiles of the residuals. It is, however, unusual for any of these (except the last, perhaps) to consist of lines that are parallel either to the fit or to each other.

Comment: @whuber It's one of the default functions in SPSS graphical editor, called "Confidence Interval for individuals." My guess is that it's the 2.5th and 97.5th percentile of the residual.

Comment: Thanks! It is interesting that SPSS would abuse standard terminology in that way (and good to know that it's no fault of yours--+1 for your answer).

Comment: @Penguin_Knight thanks but now with your explanation I am no longer sure that prediction interval is appropriate either...

Comment: @Momo. I got rid of it altogether. Feel free to edit it if you feel it can be better.

Comment: +1 I like it this way as I have no idea what this interval would be called.

Comment: I would have thought "confidence interval for individuals" would be a prediction interval ... but I am pretty sure it isn't that, because a PI 'spreads out in the tails' like a CI does (but relatively less so), while in that picture the green lines seem perfectly straight (I copied the picture and laid a straight line over them and couldn't see any deviation from linearity at all, but I guess it's possible there's just such small a deviation that it's not discernable).