Understanding the Interpretation of Confidence Intervals in Repeated Experiments
I understand that the interpretation of a 95% confidence interval (CI) is that, in the long run, 95% of such intervals computed from repeated experiments will contain the true parameter. I also know that a CI is not a probability statement about the parameter itself - we can't say that a specific observed CI has a 95% probability of containing the true value.
However, I'm trying to wrap my head around the following scenario:
Suppose we run an experiment 100 times, each time calculating a 95% confidence interval for the parameter of interest. If I randomly select one of these CIs, is it correct to say there's a 95% chance that the selected interval contains the true parameter?
Is the key difference that we can't say the same fixed CI will hold the 95% chance across repeated experiments, but rather each new repetition has a new value for the CI and each new value has a 95% chance of either containing or not?

Did you look at this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11609/clarification-on-interpreting-confidence-intervals/11727#11727 It should answer most of your questions. At least, it will give you plenty of food for thoughts.

I will try to give a traditional Frequentist answer, not to immediately run to a Bayesian critique of CIs (which is something to keep in mind, but both sides should be considered).
Denote $Y$ the data that is assumed to follow a statistical model $f_\theta$, with $\theta$ unknown and fixed, and $[L(Y), U(Y)]$ an interval that depends on the data. Then, a $1-\alpha$ confidence interval satisfies $\inf_{\theta} \mathbb{P}_{\theta}(L(Y) \leq \theta \leq U(Y)) \geq 1 - \alpha$. This means that, whatever the value of the true parameter is, considered fixed, then the probability of the interval estimator to contain the true parameter is at least $1-\alpha$, where the randomness comes from having $Y \sim f_\theta$.


we can't say that a specific observed CI has a 95% probability of containing the true value.


Following what precedes, it is not wrong to say that a confidence interval has a certain chance of containing the true value. You just need to be careful to see that what is random here is the interval, not the parameter. People are often worried about this sort of statement, as interpretations may lose this aspect of what is fixed and what is random in your design.

Suppose we run an experiment 100 times, each time calculating a 95% confidence interval for the parameter of interest. If I randomly select one of these CIs, is it correct to say there's a 95% chance that the selected interval contains the true parameter?

It is correct for 100 intervals, it would also be correct for 1 interval, provided the interpretation reflects indeed that the randomness is on the data generation, and not on the parameter. This example is right in the sense that it indicates that this traditional interpretation of CIs depends on whether the assumption of repetition of sampling $Y \sim f_\theta$ is credible or not.
